# I need TFS wit item to ask user for value for field

Tags: input, tfs

We have a tfs WIT item that has many fields, too many.  We want a value (i.e xx.xx) to be requested of a user if they select a value in a specific field.  The value the user adds would be appended to a specific field (i.e. description).  We don't have the room on the wit to add a field for the user to type it in directly.

Is there any way to generate a dialog or msgbox that requests the desired info and appends the value to an existing field? If not within the .wit itself,can a .wit call an external process (i.e. Vb exe), the exe requests the data, and somehow updates the wit?

Comment: You could create a custom control, but would need to create one for Web, each version of Visual Studio in use and Eclipse. I'd recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your own work item control. An useful source of custom control can be found at https://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/.

For Windows Controls, you will need to install the version for each of the Visual Studio editions you will use.

For Web Controls, you need to navigate in your browser to the configuration panel for the web extension of TFS: `http://servername:8080/tfs/admin/Extensions`, upload the .zip file, make sure to use the .zip file matching you TFS server version. And enable the extension.